# How can I limit contributors to sub directory of a Github repository

Tags: github

We use GitHub to host our private repository. We have multiple contributors who working on the project as contractors.

We want these contributors with limited access to only make changes to a subdirectory within the repository.Additionally, we want these contributors to read the code only within that subdirectory.(in other words anything above the subdirectory is not readable to the contributor. Is there a way to do this on Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just make additional repositories out of the subdirectories?

Comment: We are quite new at github. I will look into this. that would make sense. thank you for the idea